# How to mark a file that it was created with my program

Tags: java, file, security

I'm working on a program to help my teacher to disable cheating with homework. It is a simple text manager program to which you can not paste text and encrypts and decrypts each file in an unique way. I've already created the program, I'd just like to ask if there is a way to mark the file created by the program, that it was created by that program. Just to be sure that no one finds out how the encryptor works and creates a program that is able to create the same format. So is there a way to add an invisible key or something like that to a file that can be read only by the teacher version of the program?

Comment: If the security is based on the knowledge of how the encryptor works, then it's flawed. Encryption doesn't rely on secret algorithms. All the encryption algorithms are public and open-source. The security of encryption relies on the knowledge of a secret *key*.

Comment: Yes, but also studens have to be able to read it if they want to continue working on it, so they have to be able to decrypt it by the program, but not with anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no invisible marks that can't be made visible with reverse engineering.

And I'm afraid that if your software executes on a student's machine, there is nothing that you can do<sup>1</sup> to make it impossible for a student (or someone working for them) to reverse engineer the software.

That means they could:

- Figure out how your software is making the invisible marks and do the same thing.
- Figure out how your software is blocking copy-and-paste and subvert that.
- Figure out the mathematical algorithm that your software is using to encrypt and decrypt the data, and implement it to decrypt the data for themselves<sup>2</sup>.

Basically ... all of the measures you have implemented can be defeated.  (And they probably only need to defeat one of them to implement a cheat.)

People have suggested using public / private key encryption to you.  This does not (and cannot) solve the entire problem.  However it should allow you to build digital signatures into your anti-cheating measures.  For example, you should be able to implement a digital signature that proves that a particular version of a file was signed by someone with a specific key<sup>3</sup> at a specific time.

This is not to say that you shouldn't try.  You and your "customer" (the teacher) just need to recognize that there is a realistic possibility that your best efforts will not defeat a cheater.  (Just like in a face-to-face exam room situation!)

<sup>Actually ... IMO, *it would have been* advisable for your customer to obtain (e.g. pay for) anti-cheating software from a reputable supplier.  Getting a non-expert (you) to implement something for them "on the cheap" could be a false economy.  Just saying ....</sup>

---

<sup>1 - At least ... not to my knowledge.

2 - This includes using a public / private key encryption.  Your software would need to have one of the keys embedded in it in order to decrypt the data.  Alternatively the key should need to be stored on the machine, or fetched over the network.  In all casesm the key can be extracted or intercepted by reverse engineering.

3 - But not a specific person!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If someone works out how to create a program that creates the same format, then they'll be able to add the invisible key to the file.

If your program only needs to write the file, then you should encrypt it with a public key.  The private key used for decryption would be held only by the teacher.  The file should also contain the students name so that everyone can't just submit the same file.

Comment: It doesn't work with public and private key, the encryption of this file is a mathemathical calculation that is done by the program and it depends on the size of the text so each file is encrypted differently. And they don't really need to sign to it, because they send the homework to the teacher by e-mail and everyone has a different text to write. And the last thing is that they need to be able to decrypt it, because they may do a part of the homework at 1 time, than save it and a day later if they return to it, they need to be able to read it to see where they finnished

Answer (score -1):

I think you should move forward with the idea of creating a file as one step and security as another step. For security I would always rather go with something provided by a library, something already tested and proved secured. The strength of security is then based on security modul in use, and not in your application logic. Software security is a complex topic which requires in depth knowledge and experience. The original idea is broken in my opinion in fact that if someone is already able to recreate your unique way of encryption, he/she would also be able to write that additional piece of info in the resulting file.